# Evisions Argos - Justified Alignment

Tags: report

Does anyone know how to align in a justified manner in Rich Text Field in an Argos report? I've been searching for this in the product documentation, online help and throughout the IDE and haven't found a way of doing this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

An RTF field in Argos has left, center and right alignment, but not justified. If you'd like to see that functionality added, please submit an enhancement request to our HelpDesk. Thanks!

Comment: I would definitively like to see that functionality. Can you provide a link or explanation as to how to submit the request to your HelpDesk?